# CSS: Any way to horizontally center a header which has "position:fixed"?

Tags: css, header, center, fixed

I have a header created with two div containers, one `#header-container` and one `#header`:

```
#header_container { 
background:#eeeeee; 
border:0px hidden; 
height:100px; 
position:fixed; 
width:1000px; 
top:0; 
margin: auto; 
display: block;
}
#header { 
line-height:60px; 
margin:0 auto; 
display:block; 
width:940px; 
text-align:center;
}
```

I am of course unable to have both "fixed" and "center", so how can I center the header while keeping the "fixed" property?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `position: center`, the allowed values are:  static | relative | absolute | fixed | inherit Please correct your question.

Comment: when I replaced "fixed" with "center", the header centered, but really it was just because I got rid of "fixed", thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: When you used `position: center`, the browser ignored the property and the default of `position: static` was used, and because of `margin: auto` the `div` centered itself with respect to the root element.

Comment: Yep.  That's the tricky thing with CSS and HTML, well any programming, really- it's probably best to change only one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add "left: 50%;margin-left: -500px;" to #header-container, it will center. Don't forget to place the margin-left behind the margin: auto;

So your code will be:

```
#header_container{
background: #eeeeee;
border: 0px hidden; 
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
width: 1000px;
top:0;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -500px;
display:block;
}

#header{
line-height: 60px;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
width: 940px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I think that'll do it... I'm actually having some issues kind of understanding this all, I actually got the CSS in my OP from another post on this site.... where would you put things?  As in: <head><div "header container"><div "header"></div></div></head> ?  Or what about <div "header container"><head><div header></div</head></div> ?

Comment: DIV's should not be used in the <head></head> section. This part of your HTML file is used to tell the browser where to find scripts, style sheets and things like the title and meta tags. I would advise to use a seperate css file, which you include in your head section. Inside the <body></body> you can add the <div id="header-container"><div id="header"></div></div> part.

Comment: Gotcha, that might be the problem, it's formatting kind of funny, like it's separate from the body (obviously, because it is... having a dumb moment).

Comment: That didn't do it, unfortunately, the header is too far to the right.  But I think you've got the right idea, so if I keep adjusting it, I'll get it right.  We solved the issue of having "fixed" while having it always centered, and thanks for that!

Comment: On my screen both the container and header are centered. Could you share the CSS and HTML you have right now?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick to horizontally center a div with fixed position, of which the width is not 100%:

```
position:fixed;
background-color:grey;  /* optional */
height:100px;           /* optional but useful for most of you, choose value you want*/
width:1280px;           /* optional but useful for most of you, choose value you want*/
top:0px;                /* optional but useful for most of you, choose value you want*/
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
left:0;
right:0;
```

More info here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_left.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AJLZT/8/

Just use

```
#header {    margin: 0 30px;}
```

Comment: Do you mean to center header_container? or center header?

Answer (score 0):

This might help. You just need to add the margin-left tag in your code

---

```
#header_container{
width:1000px;
height:200px;
margin:10px;
background:orange;
position:fixed;
margin-left:350px;
}
#header { 
line-height:60px; 
margin:0 auto; 
display:block; 
width:940px; 
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 100% cure for this problem in one go.

Here you go:

First, add the bootstrap in the **"head"** in **"html"**

Then in the header, add the class **"container-fluid"**

Then in the style section, type as:

```
header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
//boom!!! problem solved.
```

Comment: This sounds like a Bootstrap CSS-specific answer, but I wasn't using Bootstrap in the question... and of course any CSS stuff from 2013 should be ignored :P things have changed so much since then...